# Outstanding medical bills - will this prevent entry into the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, health, regulations

I had my baby in America last year, and I paid part of the bills before leaving. But I lost my husband shortly after I returned home so I couldn't continue with the payment plan since I left so they took the debt to a collection agency. I have contacted the agency and am now paying according to the new payment plan am given.

I want to travel to the USA next month an I was wondering if the immigration will deny us entry.

Comment: Do you claim your child is a US citizen?

Comment: What citizenship do you (and your baby) hold? And just for completion, what citizenship was your husband?

Comment: I am so sorry for your loss.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: A baby born in the U.S. is automatically and involuntarily a U.S. citizen. It's not up to you to "claim" or "not claim".

Comment: @user102008: I don't think it's *quite* that simple.  If you are on a brief trip to the US and your baby is born, is the child instantly liable to pay US taxes on its worldwide income even if it spends only a couple days in the country in its entire life?  Some people will probably say yes, but common sense dictates otherwise, and there is no agency which goes looking for such children abroad if they fail to fulfill the obligations of US citizenship, so long as they do not claim its benefits either.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: It is ABSOLUTELY that simple. There is no ambiguity in it. Of course, the child can personally apply to renounce U.S. citizenship when they become old enough, at which point they probably haven't owed any taxes yet. If they do not renounce citizenship, they are liable for U.S. taxes their whole life even if they never step in the U.S. again. In fact, there are multiple questions on the Money StackExchange from people like this. The IRS may not put in the effort to pursue these people, but they are absolutely liable under U.S. law.

Answer (score 9):

Immigration officials do not have access to your debt information, they only have access to immigration info provided on visa forms or entry forms or court actions against you (and this later is only for serious offenses, not minor things like parking tickets).

As you are on terms with the medical service and making payments, there is no reason for this to interfer with your entry.